# Aspect oriented programming using chained Traits

Tags: php, traits

I'm currently evaluating if I'm gonna use traits in my software project. In this project I want to use aspect oriented programming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_software_development) to decouple system logic from business logic.

I want to have a logger trait and a cacheing trait.
Now the question: Is it possible to use both traits on the same class method? With a defined order of execution?

Thought Example:

```
trait Logger {
  public function warn($argument) {
    $result = parent::__FUNCTION__($argument);
    if(!$result) echo "warn";
    return $result;
  }
}

trait Cacher {
  public function cache($argument) {
    if(CACHE::contains(__FUNCTION__, $argument)) {
      return CACHE::get(__FUNCTION__, $argument);
    }
    return parent::__FUNCTION__($argument);
  }
}

class MyBusiness {
  use Logger, Cache { Logger::logger as myTest, Cache::cache as myTest before Logger }

  public function myTest(boolean $someBool) {
    return !$someBool;
  }
}
```

Order of execution should be Enter Cache::cache, Enter Logger::logger, Enter myTest return !bool, log it, cache it.

Comment: You must read more about traits and magic methods as I think you misunderstood their utility.. Also, you should consider learning about dependency injection to inject Log and Cache services whenever you need them..

Comment: @MateiMihai The hole point of aspect oriented programming is not to use dependency injection for cross cutting concerns like logging or caching https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspektorientierte_Programmierung "The so-called traits represent a similar or even equivalent solution approach."